# How to place the button to be always at the right side in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, material-design

I've a button inside the notification and I'm trying to place the button on the right side like the design below but not sure how to place it without doing style="left: 290px" because it will look weird when the page is open in different screen size.

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

```
<div>
    <div class="notification"
        [ngClass]="{'noty-error' : (noty.notificationType==1),'noty-warn': (noty.notificationType==2), 'noty-info' : (noty.notificationType==3)}"
        *ngFor="let noty of notifications;">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="noty.notificationType==1" class="noty-error-icon">highlight_off</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="noty.notificationType==2" class="noty-warn-icon">error</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="noty.notificationType==3" class="noty-info-icon">warning</mat-icon>
        <span style="color: black;">
            {{noty.message}}
        </span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="noty.notificationType==2">
            <button  mat-raised-button color="accent" [style.marginRight.px]="20"  style = "display: flex; justify-content:flex-end" matTooltip="Save Text Edit" (click)=openDialog()>
                View
            </button>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've so far
[image]

and this is the design I'm trying to do
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
    .notification {
      display:flex;
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
    }

    button{
      position:absolute;
      right:20px;
    }
```